# TypeScript array methods not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I am wrestling with some serious issues. I was trying to use in my code several array methods like push, includes, filter. None of them works.
     `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Simple use of push:

```
  users: User[];
  user = new User('','','','','','','','','');

  addUser(user){
    this.usersService.addUser(user)
    .subscribe(
      user => this.users.push(user),
      error => this.errMsg = <any> error);
  }
```

UPDATE: Accidentally commented out initialization of Users.

```
this.getUsers();  

if(this.users.find(this.checkLogin) === undefined){
  console.log('OK no login like this');
}else{
  console.log('Login like this exists');
}
checkLogin(element){
  return element === this.user.login;
}

getUsers(){
  this.usersService.getUsers()
  .subscribe(
    users => this.users = users,
    error => this.errMsg = <any> error);
}
```

Still getting error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: You posted a whole lot of irrelevant code and configuration. **Read** the message carefully. Make sense of it: "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined". So it tries accessing `push` on some object (`this.users`), but this object (`this.users`) is undefined. Something is undefined when you have never initialized it. Have you initialized `this.users`? No, you haven't. You have just declared it.

Comment: You need to initialize the variable, all you're doing in that code is declaring users and its type.

Comment: OK, now you need to understand asynchronism. Why doesn't getUsers() return an array of users? Why does it return an Observable instead, that forces you to subscribe, pass a callback, and finally obtain the users inside the callback? Because the service call is **asynchronous**. As the first A in AJAX. So, once you've called getUsers(), all you have done is telling the service: I'm interested in getting users. Please call me back when they are available. Right after that, they are **not** available. They will be available muuuch later, after the response has come back from the server.

Comment: I understand that just wasnt 100% sure. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
 users: User[];
```

To:

```
  users: User[] = [];
```

Comment: Why the first one doesn't work even when i add object to array through service I don't get it. Is it asynchronus or what

Comment: @quimak The first one is a type declaration; go to www.typescriptlang.org and learn some basics.

Comment: @quimak the getUser function returns immediately while the service response happens later. Therefore users isn't initialized before your if statement is execute. Try `if(this.users && this.users.find(...))` but this question isn't really about Angular.